# save object in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

is it possible to save an object in db android?
is this the correct way to do it?

```
public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(o);
            out.close();

            // Get the bytes of the serialized object
            byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

            return buf;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend agaist storing whole object as a byte array. If it is a class, save it is attributes then create it when you need it. If it is whole file, just write it into internal/external storage.

Comment: thanks for your recomendation

Comment: Yes, it's possible to store BLOBs in SQLite. But I would NOT recommend to. Instead, I'd recommend to store the file path only.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do if you want to save and retrieve an object into sqlite, is to use an ORM (Object-relational mapping).
You map the fields of your object with the fields of your table.

Some Android ORM:

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml)

[GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com)

[SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar)

Comment: You may also consider [JDXA](http://www.softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html), a simple, non-intrusive, and flexible ORM for Android.